# JS Draw a multicolor spiral in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spiral

I'm trying to draw a multicoloured archimedean spiral on a HTML5 canvas.
My final goal is to make a datavisualisation of a sound record, it would be a kind of static spiral timeline. Each color represents an event in the sound record.
I checked for many days on the web but couldn't find something really matching my goal.
I'm used to PHP but not to JS.
I got the [base source code for drawing a spiral](http://jsfiddle.net/jingshaochen/xJc7M/) in my script.

The point is I'm getting the hexadecimal value and the length in pixels for each color from a json array.
Each coloured section should follow each other right after on the spiral, no shading effects.
I don't know how to get the ending position of the last coloured section to start drawing the new colour section. The result of the following code makes all the colors superimposed.

Thanks for your help !

Here's my JS code :

```
var lengthOfColors = ["29.47965973","45.35332267","70.29765013"]; 
var colorCodes = ["#000","#807f29","#c0c0c0"]; // the real arrays are much longers

var c = document.getElementById('c');
var context = c.getContext("2d");
var centerx = context.canvas.width / 2;
var centery = context.canvas.height / 2;

$('#draw').click(function() 
{
a = parseFloat($('#a').val());
    b = parseFloat($('#b').val()); //The user can define Cosinus and Sinus

    context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(centerx, centery);

for (var beg = 0, end = lengthOfColors.length; beg < end; beg++)
  {
  for (i = 0; i < lengthOfColors[beg]; i++)
    {
    angle = 0.1 * i;//Angle of line rotation = 0.1
    x = centerx + (a * angle) * Math.cos(angle);
    y = centery + (b * angle) * Math.sin(angle);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    }
  context.strokeStyle = colorCodes[beg];
  context.stroke();//draw the path
  };
});
```

Here's my HTML code :

```
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<br/>
Cosinus: <input id="a" type="text" value='1'/>
<br/>
Sinus: <input id="b" type="text" value='1'/>
<br/>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Putf/)

I changed the colors to make it easier to see. I moved the `beginPath();`-method inside the first for-loop so that it could start to draw a new color each time. Next, I set the `moveTo()`-method to start at where the location of the previous line ended. In the next for loop, I used a single variable `curIteration` outside of the scope to keep track of how far the drawing had come. Javascript:

```
var lengthOfColors = ["29.47965973","45.35332267","70.29765013"]; 
var colorCodes = ['purple','red','green']; // the real arrays are much longers

var c = document.getElementById('c');
var context = c.getContext("2d");
var centerx = context.canvas.width / 2;
var centery = context.canvas.height / 2;

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    a = parseFloat($('#a').val());
    b = parseFloat($('#b').val()); //The user can define Cosinus and Sinus

    context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(centerx, centery);
    // Temporarily store prev location
    var x = centerx, y = centery, curIteration = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfColors.length; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x, y);

        for (; curIteration < lengthOfColors[i]; curIteration++) {
            angle = 0.1 * curIteration;//Angle of line rotation = 0.1
            x = centerx + (a * angle) * Math.cos(angle);
            y = centery + (b * angle) * Math.sin(angle);
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            console.log('x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
        }

        console.log(colorCodes[i]);
        context.strokeStyle = colorCodes[i];
        context.stroke();//draw the path
    }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<br/>
<form>
Cosinus: <input id="a" type="text" value='20'/>
<br/>
Sinus: <input id="b" type="text" value='20'/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Draw" />
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your quick response ! Works almost perfect.
It seems the main colors lengths are taking over the smallest ones by superimposing. I'll investigate tomorrow deeply and try to post a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help. But I don't understand what it is that's not working?

Comment: Ok, I figured out, the loop takes only the next biggest length.
For example if we have the chain ['10','20','30','15','40','32','45','17'] it will avoid the '15' and the '32' but in every test I made will compute the last length, even if its lower, '17' here. I'll try to solve it today.

Comment: Why not perform a sort on the length array (and color array) before drawing?

Comment: Because each color represents an event on a soundtrack, so their order is volunteer, they follow a predefined timeline (like 5second of drums then 1 minute of piano then 30 seconds of loud noise etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Say33/spmvq/2/)

Ok I got the solution from a user on http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/js-dessiner-une-spirale-multicolore-en-javascript
I passed down the cumulates length value as an argument of the loop.
Thanks again for your help !
Here's the entire JS code with the true arrays :

```
//Fork of http://jsfiddle.net/jingshaochen/xJc7M/ with the big help of bvx89 on StackOverFlow.com and 007julien on http://fr.openclassrooms.com
var cumLengthOfColors = [29.47965973,74.8329824,145.1306325,244.9079424,256.2462731,371.8972459,380.9679104,383.2355765,505.6895477,507.9572139,519.2955445,605.4668576,632.6788512,634.9465173,700.7088352,780.0771499,877.5867936,882.1221259,1199.595385,1208.666049,1210.933715,1242.681041,1251.751706,1254.019372,1408.220669,1412.756001,1498.927314,1507.997979,1510.265645,1512.533311,1521.603975,1526.139308,1535.209972,1548.815969,1553.351301,1639.522614,1641.790281,1684.875937,1693.946602,1696.214268,1707.552598,1712.087931,1791.456245,2192.833151];
var colorCodes = ['#ffffff','#807f29','#c0c0c0','#ffffff','#00fd5b','#807f29','#808080','#98cdfa','#ffffff','#c0c0c0','#00fd5b','#ffffff','#808080','#00fd5b','#807f29','#c0c0c0','#ffffff','#c0c0c0','#ffffff','#808080','#00807f','#ffffff','#808080','#00807f','#ffffff','#00fd5b','#807f29','#808080','#00fd5b','#807f29','#808080','#00fd5b','#807f29','#808080','#00fd5b','#807f29','#98cdfa','#ffffff','#808080','#00807f','#ffffff','#00fd5b','#807f29','#ffffff'];

var c = document.getElementById('c');
var context = c.getContext("2d");
context.lineWidth=20;
var centerx = context.canvas.width / 2;
var centery = context.canvas.height / 2;

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    a = parseFloat($('#a').val());
    b = parseFloat($('#b').val()); //The user can define Cosinus and Sinus

    context.clearRect(0, 0, 2200, 2200);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(centerx, centery);
    // Temporarily store prev location
    var x = centerx;
    var y = centery;
    var curIteration = 0;
    for (var i = 0, c = cumLengthOfColors.length; i < c; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x, y);

        for (; curIteration < cumLengthOfColors[i]; curIteration++) {
            angle = 0.1 * curIteration;
            x = centerx + (a * angle) * Math.cos(angle);
            y = centery + (b * angle) * Math.sin(angle);
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            console.log('x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);


        console.log(colorCodes[i]);
        context.strokeStyle = colorCodes[i];
        context.stroke();
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<form>
Cosinus: <input id="a" type="text" value='5'/>
<br/>
Sinus: <input id="b" type="text" value='5'/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Dessiner" />
</form>
<canvas id="c" width="2200" height="2200"></canvas>
```